# Multiply TIME in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have this query below, basically I'm trying to subtract 2 dates and get the hours.

However, I need the subtracted time to be multiplied by the number of cleaners

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(TIME, ClientBooking.TimeEnd - ClientBooking.TimeStart) AS HoursWorked2,
    ClientBooking.NumberOfCleaners AS NumberOfCleaners,
    ClientBooking.TimeStart,
    ClientBooking.TimeEnd,
    ClientBooking.ClientID,
    ((((ClientInfo.FirstName + N' ') +
        ClientInfo.LastName) + N'  ') +
        ClientInfo.Company) AS ClientName,
    ((((ClientInfo.Address + N' - ') +
        ClientInfo.City) + N' - ') +
        ClientInfo.ZipCode) AS Address,
    ((ClientInfo.PhoneNumber + N'  ') +
      ClientInfo.EmailAddress) AS Contact,
    (ClientBooking.HourlyRate / 60) AS MinRate,
    (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,ClientBooking.TimeStart,ClientBooking.TimeEnd) * ClientBooking.NumberOfCleaners) AS Quantity,
    ClientBooking.HourlyRate,
    DATEDIFF(HOUR, ClientBooking.TimeStart, ClientBooking.TimeEnd) AS HoursWorked
FROM 
    (dbo.ClientBooking ClientBooking
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.ClientInfo ClientInfo ON (ClientInfo.ClientID = ClientBooking.ClientID))
```

Basically, I need to multiply the result of this:

```
 CONVERT(TIME,"ClientBooking"."TimeEnd" - "ClientBooking"."TimeStart" )
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping everything in double quotes? It makes this absolutely horrible to look at. As posted this is just a wall of text that is indecipherable.

Comment: because this is a Expression from Devexpress without it the solution wont work.

Comment: also what you need to know is just this part 

        CONVERT(TIME,"ClientBooking"."TimeEnd" - "ClientBooking"."TimeStart" )

Comment: Try this - http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/calculate-time-operations-in-sql-server.aspx

Comment: What are the data types of `TimeEnd` and `TimeStart`? `TIME` isn't a duration or something you can multiply, it is a point in time, so I suspect you shouldn't be using that data type here at all. Do you need to multiply by the number of minutes? Don't you already do that (3rd last expression)?

Comment: TimeEnd and TimeStart are DateTime 
I have the value in minutes, but im but as this Sh** Devexpress XtraReports dont allow me to work with the variables i need it to be shown in Date format not in Minutes, so if i could get the time in format like HH:MM:SS instead of number of minutes, i could display it in the Invoice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How About using this:

```
    Select 
convert(time,DATEADD(MINUTE, ( convert(float,(DATEDIFF(minute, ClientBooking.TimeStart, ClientBooking.TimeEnd) * ClientBooking.NumberOfCleaners))/60), ''))
FROM 
    (dbo.ClientBooking ClientBooking
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.ClientInfo ClientInfo ON (ClientInfo.ClientID = ClientBooking.ClientID))
```

Sorry if i have missed a parenthesis !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATEDIFF() function..
Something like:

```
DATEDIFF(hour, ClientBooking.TimeStart, ClientBooking.TimeEnd) * ClientBooking.NumberOfCleaners
```

as your desired column!

Comment: but i also need the minutes xD

Comment: So you can use minute instead of hour and divide the result by 60 if you need it in hours

Comment: When you want "hours" in this situation you usually want to use minutes and then convert to hours your final result.   1 hour 59 minutes may not mean 1 hour to you.

Comment: the problem with dividing with 60 is:
if I have 121 minutes and divide that for 60 I will not get 2:02 minutes I will get: 2.033333......
So.. looks like there is no way to do  what i want in the SQL side.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly this could help you:

```
declare @start datetime = '2018-11-02 07:00:00'
declare @end datetime = '2018-11-02 08:03:00'
declare @diff int

Select @diff = DATEDIFF(minute,@start,@end)

Select case 
    when @diff < 60 then concat('00:', right('0' + convert(varchar,@diff), 2))
    when @diff >= 60 and @diff < 120 then '01:' + right('0' + convert(varchar,@diff - 60), 2)
    when @diff >= 120 and @diff < 180 then '02:' + right('0' + convert(varchar,@diff - 120), 2)
    when @diff >= 180 and @diff < 240 then '03:' + right('0' + convert(varchar,@diff - 180), 2)
end
```

Of course you would need to add the following hours as well.

I've splitted everything up, so it is easier to understand. But you should be able to write it in one line and without variables as well

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will try this and get you to know asap

Comment: But with the result, you wont be able to multiply with another field.. To multiply you would need to change the part after the `then`, and keep it as an int...

Comment: not a very charmin solution but it does the job. gonna have to increment this List up to 100 hours, but i will probably do a macro